# How do I set a Twig | length variable with a certain status from an array of items from a ACF related field in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

So if I am trying to get the number of products 'In Stock' (that are related to my Product post) in Timber/Twig `{% set prods_avail = post.product_items.stock_status == 'In Stock' | count %}` I would like to loop thru the count of products that show = "In Stock" and then display the count using `{{ prods_avail }}`

I am using ACF meta fields and must go thru Product post field of `product_items` into the related post field and see if the field `stock_status` evaluates to `'In Stock'` from a select dropdown.

For example, `{% set prods_count = post.product_items | count %}` and using `{{ prods_count }}` get me the number of products in the array (in this example `5`)

Again, these are the products attached (or related) to the `product_items` field of the main Post:

```
product_item1 = 'In Stock'
product_item2 = 'In Stock'
product_item3 = 'No Stock'
product_item4 = 'No Stock'
product_item5 = 'In Stock'
```

I would like be able to have my variable output `{{ prods_avail }}` a value of `3` which are the total products 'In Stock'

~ Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the collection with the filter [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html)

```html
{% set prods_avail = post.product_items|filter(v => v.stock_status == 'In Stock')|length %}
```

---

The filter `filter` was added in twig v. 2.10. so if this is not available (in timber), you would need to loop all items and create a counter

```html
{% set prods_avail = 0 %}
{% for product_item in post.product_items %}
    {% if product_item.stock_status == 'In Stock' %}
        {% set prods_avail = prods_avail + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#e0adc41f81)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - This works fine for me either way!